# Trying to split/sort file by month from date

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to make separate files for each month over multiple years so I can edit/analyze data for per months, like for every year januari etc.. However, I tried a code I used to sort data per ID and thought with a few adjustments I could use it again. But I've tried multiple things and it still doens't work

The data are line likes these:

```
"Datum","Rentedatum","Bedrag","Rekening","Tegenrekening","Naam","Omschrijving"
"2017-06-09","2017-06-09","20,00","Owner bank acc","3rdparty bank acc","name","Action"
```

I've edited it that it read the new file, the correct row etc. But i can't get it to read the corresponding months.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Mutaties.csv')
df['Datum'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datum'], format='%Y/%m/%d')
print (df)

for id in df['Datum'].unique():
    df[
       (df['Datum'].dt.month == 1)].to_csv(f"Januari.csv")<code>
```

and i've tried it in this format

```
df[
       (df['Datum'].dt.month=='2')].to_csv(f"Februari.csv")
```

Datum is the column in `df` which contains the date, i've also tried 01 instead of 1. Nothing worked

The date is formatted in 2017-09-16

Everytime i run the script it gives the following error:

````
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'month'```
````

Comment: `df['Datum'].dt.month==2`

Comment: It's `df['Datum'].dt.month`. But besides that your loop doesn;t make any sense. You are looping over each `Date` and then doing nothing with it in your loop.

Comment: What you want is `df['Datum'].dt.month == id`. Or more elegant: `for grp, dfg in df.groupby('Datum'): dfg.to_csv(f'month_{grp}')`

Comment: Am I not writing it to a new .csv file? Because I used it this way before and it worked back then with a dataset of 36k lines instead of the 300 right now.

Answer (score 0):

Add `.dt.month` to all lines instead of only the first 2.
What [Erfan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9081267/erfan) said worked, It was indeeed .dt.month, i was stupid enought to only add .dt. at the first 2 lines

```
    df[
       (df['Datum'].dt.month == 1)].to_csv(f"Januari.csv")
```